# Сериализация объекта класса, приведенного к типу object

Tags: unity3d

Есть некоторая структура, например:

```
[Serializable]
public struct ArrowWalleyStats
{
    public Damage damage;
    public float radius;
    public int countOfArrows;
    public float cooldown;
}
```

И есть класс, который хранит в себе экземпляр этой структуры, но, по некоторым причинам, хранит его как переменную типа `object`. Например так:

```
[Serializable]
class ArrowWalley
{
    object stats = new ArrowWalleyStats();
}
```

При попытке сериализовать объект класса ArrowWalley стандартным классом Unity `JsonUtility.ToJson(new ArrowWalley());`, поле stats не сериализуется.

Как можно добиться сериализации поля `stats`? Желательно, используя все тот же стандартный класс `JsonUtility`.

Comment: стандартный Unity Json сериализатор не поддерживает полиморфизм. А чтобы легче понять, как он работает - точно также как работает Editor в Unity. Все то, что отображается в Editor (поля класса в инспекторе), также и в Json будет сериализоваться

Answer (score -1):

У вас поле stats не помечено, как сериализуемое. Соответственно сериализация и не происходит.
Чтобы оно сериализовалось нужно либо делать его публичным, либо использовать атрибут [[SerializeField]](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeField.html)